# How to highlight a column while filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, primeng-datatable

I have been using Angular 4 with primeng 4 . When sorting is done with
`p-datatable` of primeng it highlights the column header being sorted. 
Example : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/sort

But when filtering is done here, the column header is not highlighted .
Example : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

When I checked  with chromebug, I was able to see every time sorting is done , a class gets added : `ui-state-active` , but this class does not get added while filtering .

**Can anybody suggest me as to how I can highlight a column header while filtering like it's being done in sort in the example up above ?**

Comment: use [ngClass] and add .ui-state-active when filter is used

Comment: @porgo : Yes , I understand that . But where will I add the code ? I cannot very well add it to the library .

Answer (score -1):

style="#{car.remarks eq rsm.search ? 'color:red':'color:blue'}"

Comment: car = datatable variable.  remarks = column name,rsm = bean name,search = String variable create in bean,eq =  equals (here if the search contains equal to the column value then the color became red,else blue ,capital letter and small letter also listen)

Comment: Please add your comments to the answer so that they can be easily read by people visiting the question.

Comment: please update your answer with the content of your comment. Use the `edit` function